# Пустой req.body, когда отправляю файлы и данные с помощью FormData()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Суть такова - на фронте крутится Angular 5. Создаю этим кодом FormData() и кидаю туда файлы и свои данные:

```
let output_form = new FormData()

let files: FileList = this.files;

if(files.length > 0){
  for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    output_form.append('photos', files[i], files[i].name)
  }
}

output_form.append('jsondata', JSON.stringify(this.formAddItem));

this.dataForm = output_form;

this._productService.addProduct(this.token, this.dataForm).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data.json())
  },
  err => console.log(err)
)
```

На серваке стоит node.js + express. Пытаюсь получить тело запроса

```
.post('/', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req);

})
```

Получаю пустой объект. 
Использую на сервере

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так же не работает req.body и req.params.

Comment: Чтобы принять файлы, одного body-parser будет мало, понадобится модуль типа [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: @Darth а по подробней можно? Просто дело не только в файлах, а то что я не вижу застрингованный json. Т.е. просто {}.

Comment: @Darth дошло, поставил multer и сделал upload.array(). и все робит) спасибо большое!

Comment: Очень интересная ситуация. Плагин multer сохраняет сразу фото, а после чего мы можем обратиться к body и делать валидацию. Как то тупо. Походу или в нём  делать валидацию или ставить до кучи body-parcer

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @Darth за ответ.

Вообщем суть такова - когда отправляешь запрос с файлом и body на сервер, необходимо библиотекой multer сначала загрузить файлы, а затем считать данные из body.

Я сделал это вот таким образом.

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/avatars')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname);
}
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Сначала подключаем multer в наш контроллер, затем создаем правило для хранилища, где указываем в поле destination наше хранилище (путь к нему), а в поле filename указываем способ генерации уникального имени для нашего файла (я делаю текущую дату + само имя файла).

Затем в методе контроллера, например метод put я могу получить и body запроса, и доступ к файлам через req.files(если загружаем несколько файлов) или req. file (если загружаем один файл)

```
.put('/', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);
    })
})
```

Обязательным параметром для данного типа запроса является наш объект upload, где мы указываем метод загрузки (array или single), а как параметром передаем название поля, где содержаться наши файлы.

Надеюсь кому либо пригодиться.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте может поможет у меня так а в остальном также и работает

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false,limit:'5mb'}));
```